# C# - Windows Form Design

Tags: c#, oop, user-interface, uml

I am fairly new to the world of GUI programming and have written a simple GUI for an application I am building in C#. The GUI is quite simple, only consisting of a single windows form. My question is regarding the standard practices for Object Orientation with GUI's and their user inputs.

In my GUI class I currently have member variables for all the GUI related objects (buttons, labels, selection boxes, etc.) but I also have variables which store the user inputs(ex. selectedFilePath, latIndex, longIndex, etc.) that will simply pass their values to other objects when the user clicks run. Is it standard practice to keep these variables in the same class until a button is clicked and then either pass them to or create another object or should I be doing something else?

current UML class diagram:
[Sample Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0ez.jpg)

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's standard practice to separate your UI layer from your presentation logic layer to keep your UI as clean and light-weight (and thus as testable) as possible.  This also has the added benefit of adhering to [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  There are many patterns you can study to accomplish this: [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), and so on.

Typically, you only want your UI classes to contain elements which are *specific* to the particular UI technology (i.e. controls, etc.).

By doing it this way, you can create mock classes for all your UI elements which you can then use with your favorite testing framework to build tests against the presentation logic and the underlying business and domain logic.

Comment: Thanks roryap, I had a feeling this wasn't the right way to do it and now I know. I didn't want to start building something only for it to be wrong.

Comment: @DaveT -- No problem.  Good luck.